# Conditionally quitting early on a chain of promises without throwing an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

In my node js app, I'm trying to create a registration route that takes a few asynchronous steps.  In an early step, there's a condition where I want to stop and just return a message, but I'm getting confused about mixing conditions into the promises.

My specific question is in comments in the following psuedo-code:

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
    var identity = req.body.identity;
    var password = req.body.password;

    // can't register without a reservation
    hasReservation(identity).then(function(hasReservation) {
        if (hasReservation) { return register(identity, password); }
        else {
            // stuck here: I want to say:
            res.json({ registered: false, reason: "missing reservation" });
            // and then I want to stop further promises
            // but this isn't an error, I don't want to throw an error here
        }
    }).then(function(user) {
        // in my app, registering an existing user is okay
        // I just want to reset a few things about the user and save
        // but I don't want to be here if there's no reservation
        if (user) {
            user.foo = 'bar';
            return user.save().then(function() { return user; });
        } else {
            return register(identity, password);
        }
    }).then(function(user) {
        // I want to do more asynch stuff here
    }).then(function(result) {
        res.json(result);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        res.status(500).json(error);
    });
});
```

How can I conditionally "bail out" after that first promise completes, without throwing an error?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/qx#breakwith-and-endfunction

Comment: The `async` utility might come handy for that kind of control flow where you do a lot of async work, but still want to keep control over your flow AND readability (not end with callback hell) : http://caolan.github.io/async/

Comment: @topheman - There is no reason to move from promises to the async library.  Promises have plenty of control to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If register(identity, password) returns a promise, you can reorganise your code as follows:

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
    var identity = req.body.identity;
    var password = req.body.password;

    // can't register without a reservation
    hasReservation(identity)
    .then(function(hasReservation) {
        if (hasReservation) { 
            return register(identity, password)
            .then(function(user) {
                // in my app, registering an existing user is okay
                // I just want to reset a few things about the user and save
                // but I don't want to be here if there's no reservation
                if (user) {
                    user.foo = 'bar';
                    return user.save().then(function() { return user; });
                } else {
                    return register(identity, password);
                }
            })
            .then(function(user) {
                // I want to do more asynch stuff here
            })
            .then(function(result) {
                res.json(result);
            })
        } else {
            // stuck here: I want to say:
            res.json({ registered: false, reason: "missing reservation" });
            // and then I want to stop further promises
            // but this isn't an error, I don't want to throw an error here
        }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        res.status(500).json(error);
    });
});
```

Otherwise, if register(..) just returns a value, wrap the FIRST instance of the register(...) in a Promise.resolve

```
        return Promise.resolve(register(identity, password))
```

Comment: @user1272965 - Yep, reorganization of the flow is the right answer here.  There is no way to stop downstream `.then()` handlers without rejecting or without fulfilling with a value that all downstream handlers will conditionally check and pass on.  Much easier to only have the `.then()` handlers on the branch that you want them to execute on.

Comment: okay.  thanks @jfriend00 and Jaromanda.  i get it.  sometimes you just have to indent.

Comment: technically you don't have to indent, you can write it on one line if you like, but I know what you mean